# Replace string with react component with .replace

Tags: reactjs

I have a long text (string), I want the user to be able to highlight any word he wants, and make this word a `Tag` component.

```
function highlightingString() {

    document.onmouseup = () => {
        const myHighlightedString = window.getSelection().toString(); // Gives me the word I highglight
        const startHighlightedString = docText.indexOf(myHighlightedString) // Give me the start index of my word in the document
        const endHighlightedString = startHighlightedString + myHighlightedString.length // Give me the end index of my word in the document


        newDocText = docText.replace(myHighlightedString, <Tag name={"Highlighted"}/>)

        setOpenedFile(newDocText)

    };

}
```

**Tag component**

```
function Tag({name}){
    const color = colors[name];
    return <div style={{backgroundColor: color, ...tagStyle}}>{name}<span style={{cursor: "pointer", paddingLeft: '10px'}}</span></div>
}
```

**Example:**

Initial document text: "Hello, I would like to order a pizza with peperoni"

If the user selects "pizza with", I would like to happen:

"Hello, I would like to order a *Tag name={highlighted}* /> peperoni" # Where *Tag* is simply adding a  to the selected word

Instead, I get:
"Hello, I would like to order a [object Object] peperoni"

It seems that I am replacing correctly the string I highlight with the `<Tag />` component, however I do not get why is not rendering the text within `<span>` but `[object Object]`

Comment: Well `.replace()` is a *string* method replacing one substring with another substring. And `Tag` is a react component, which is an object. So when using replace, it will literally convert that object into a string (resulting in "[object Object]") and use that for the replacement. You can't render react components that way. I dunno the context of your code, but usually you control conditional rendering within a component. If you're trying to insert react into an DOM node outside of your react stuff, then you'll have to use `ReactDOM.render` from `react-dom` to inject it.

Comment: one problem i can see is that you are mixing `react` with regular javascript. `<Tag>` is an object by design, when it renders it'll output DOM elements. Therefore replacing a string with object isn't going to work.

Comment: The thing I do not understand is: since my Tag component is returning a html element (string+span), should it be considered a string in the .replace function?

Comment: Your Tag is not returning html element. It is returning React element, which is simple JS object, serving as a description for the React Component to be created. JSX notation is returning React element.

Answer (score -1):

Well, replacing part of the string with an object will not magically insert that object into that string :) What it does is converting your object to its string representation (which is `[object Object]`) and then inserting that representation into the string.

What you want to do is to create a proper React component.
Something like this:

```
<>
    {openFile.textBeforeHighlighted}
    <Tag name={openFile.highlighted}/>
    {openFile.textAfterHighlighted}
</>
```

while your handler function sets `openFile` to something like this:

```
setOpenFile({
    textBeforeHighlighted:textBeforeHighlighted,
    highlighted:highlighted,
    textAfterHighlighted:textAfterHighlighted
});
```